# Showing Error "usb 5-2 device descriptor read/64 error -71 >a start job is running for ubuntu live cd installer"

Tags: boot, software-installation

I installed ubuntu today, followed the installation process. I installed it with a bootable DVD that I created. I choose to install it alongside my Windows 7. It went through the installation process, and completed it.

It asked me to restart the computer to finalise the installation. Suddenly, the installation disc popped out automatically and gone inside the CD/DVD drive again. It next shows me the error that I mentioned above. 
Please suggest what I should do.

I also have a Windows Repair Disc, in case I will have to uninstall Ubuntu, it could be done using Command Prompt.

Please help me, I am a beginner of Linux, so don't know much about the terminal and Linux commands.

Comment: How did you create the bootable DVD? There's a chance that it didn't burn correctly.

Comment: I download the Ubuntu ISO using uTorrent. And I burned it using ImgBurn, and also verified the burning using the "Verify' feature. There were no errors, and no misreads. So I don't think there's at all a burning error or one of installation.

Comment: If you reboot the computer, does it come up into a GRUB menu, or does it boot Windows, Ubuntu, or Ubuntu DVD?

Comment: ps: if you unplug all USB devices, does the computer boot without the USB error?

Comment: If you still have this issue please boot the live media, open a terminal and [edit] the output of `lsusb` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Thanks everyone helping me. The issue has been resolved. The issue was actually a hardware error. I read it's solution here: http://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error. I quickly took out all the cables and error gone. Thanks again for helping me everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal that the DVD is ejected at the end of the installation just before reboot. The installer even tells you so and asks you to confirm it. It also tells you to *remove the DVD from the drive* so that your computer can boot the new Ubuntu installation from the internal drive. If you leave the DVD in the drive tray the tray will be closed again during boot and the computer may boot from the DVD instead of the internal drive.

For more info see [How do I install Ubuntu?](/q/6328/175814)

Comment: It's good that the DVD gets ejected normally. But, when it ejected, I didn't removed the installation DVD and it went in. Now I am stuck with the error:

Comment: So take it out again? If that doesn't help there is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am new too, but found that if I select (yours may be different) a key to hold down during boot from NO POWER, it lets me go to the CMOS utility. From that control I select which drive to boot into. Each side has to have its own set of drivers too.

Answer (score 0):

Have an MSI 990FXA-GD65 MB with older (WIN8) UEFI support options. Run lubuntu, started having usb device descriptor read/64, error -110 problem (and others) after 17.10 upgrade. Nailed several issues to the wall, finally determined that this one was due to usb power being off during UEFI start-up. What "fixed" the problem on my system was turning the ErP function ON. That evidently delays powering up the usb hubs long enough to preclude the error checks. Suspect the root cause is in some way related to secure boot implementation, as it is preceded by errors related to loading the db that the boot loader uses.